# How do I open ISO's on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

I like Windows better than Ubuntu and want to install windows on my ubuntu laptop.  It had windows on it before.  Can anyone help me with how to open ISO's on Ubuntu?

Comment: Hey there are several questions regarding how to open an ISO. Just search askubuntu.com, e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/411793/mount-iso-using-the-terminal or if you want to create an USB stick have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick or http://askubuntu.com/questions/236599/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows-but-to-install-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu nor any other OS can read ISOs, but you can write them onto your boot device.

### 1. Get Brasero Disc burner.

`sudo apt-get install brasero`

### 2. Insert your desired boot device.

(e.g. a RW DVD, an SD Card, or a USB thumb drive)

### 3. Open Brasero

#### 3A.

Click on "Burn Image" [image]

#### 3B.

Click on the selected button then browse your computer for the Windows ISO file you downloaded.

[image]

#### 3C.

When you have found and loaded the ISO onto the program, select the device you want to write to.

#### 3D.

Before you proceed, make sure your boot device has enough memory to hold the ISO. When you're done selecting it, press "Create Image".

### 4. And you're done!

When Brasero finishes creating the image, take your boot device out and use it. You're done!